# Live Html Push Notifications

Tags: javascript, java, php, android, html

I have a question. I found out how to use javascript to send Notifications from by site (Push Notification). I made a app for android phones that just views the site but receives the notifications. How can I make it so while the app is running in the background, I can send Live notifications to the site with out refresh. If you need more info let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you need to use GoogleCloudmessaging. Please check this side out: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/